# Using REST complex type and JavaScript to fetch/get Client ID and secret?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest, csom

So for the last couple of days I have been looking for a way to get information on installed custom Add-ins (their Name, Client ID, Client secret and its expiration date) and display it, by using a SharePoint-hosted add-in, on my Dev site.

Overall purpose is to have all that information to track when Client secret expires. I know that [MS describes the process of replacing client secret](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726681.aspx#sectionSection1) and part of it is acquiring the list of apps and their client secret expiry dates.However I would like to have it in more readable form (as I will not be the only person that needs to keep track of the expiry dates) and maybe later on add some kind of email notifications.

Case is that I could not find any kind, of even simplest, example of how I could use REST complex type (ie. [AppPrincipalConfiguration or AppPrincipalCredentialReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600183.aspx#bk_AppPrincipalConfiguration), with Javascript.

I would really appreciate anything that I could hook on to, to get started...
Maybe I just don't know how to connect the dots between JSOM and REST complex type or is it even doable?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so shortly - what I wanted to achieve is a no go.

But I will use this: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/Tenant%20Information%20Portal

I hope this will help someone, it sure helped to solve my problem - Tracking the expiry of client secret.